# Having trouble iterating over the right children to change their color

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm looking to make a menu where there are more than one wxStaticTexts and when one of them is clicked it turns black and the rest are/revert back to being grey (if they were clicked before, otherwise they would just stay grey)

The problem is I usurped this code which works great for doing the first part, it turns the item that was clicked black, but it doesn't turn the rest back to grey. My attempt at a solution is in the else block. I haven't attempted anything else because I'm still figuring both C++ and WxWidgets out and I still don't have a complete understanding of some concepts used in this snippet.

```
void MyFrame::OnMenuTxtBtnLeftClickPanel(wxMouseEvent& event) {

wxObject* obj = event.GetEventObject();
wxPanel* objPanel = ((wxPanel*)obj);
wxWindowList objChild = objPanel->GetChildren();

    for (wxWindowList::iterator it = objChild.begin(); it != objChild.end(); it++) {

        wxStaticText* aStaticText = dynamic_cast<wxStaticText*>(*it);

        if (aStaticText) {
            aStaticText->SetForegroundColour(wxColour("#000000"));
        }
        else {
            // Doesn't do anything when compiled
            // it should change the StaticTexts that weren't clicked back to grey
            dynamic_cast<wxStaticText*>(*it)->SetForegroundColour(wxColour("#C8C6C6"));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is wxWindowList your implementation?

Comment: @kiner_shah What do you mean by implementation? If you want to know if it works, it does because like I said it's not by code. I'm just having trouble with iterating over the other children, I don't know what to do to have them as variables like I do the first child

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing in else block? If dynamic cast fails, you are again doing dynamic cast and trying to set foreground color?

Comment: @kiner_shah You can forget the dynamic cast and everything in the else block. I want to make it so that every child that's is not `aStaticText` to have a foreground of #C8C6C6

Comment: Does simple `it->SetForegroundColor` work?

Comment: @kiner_shah no it gives me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```cpp
void MyFrame::OnMenuTxtBtnLeftClickPanel(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    wxWindow* cur = wxDynamicCast(event.GetEventObject(),wxWindow);
    wxColor fg = m_panel1->GetForegroundColour();

    wxWindowList& children = m_panel1->GetChildren();

    for ( auto it = children.begin() ; it != children.end() ; ++it )
    {
        wxWindow* win = *it;
        if ( wxDynamicCast(win, wxStaticText) )
        {
            if ( win == cur )
            {
                win->SetForegroundColour(wxColour("#000000"));
            }
            else
            {
                win->SetForegroundColour(fg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, `m_panel1` is a `wxPanel` that is the parent of all the static texts.

On GTK, it looks like this:

[image: animated gif if static texts changing color when clicked]

The handler was bound to each static text control in the frame constructor like this:

```cpp
    m_staticText1->Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,&MyFrame::OnMenuTxtBtnLeftClickPanel,this);
    m_staticText2->Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,&MyFrame::OnMenuTxtBtnLeftClickPanel,this);
    m_staticText3->Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,&MyFrame::OnMenuTxtBtnLeftClickPanel,this);
    m_staticText4->Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,&MyFrame::OnMenuTxtBtnLeftClickPanel,this);
```

`m_staticText1`, etc. should be changed to the names you're using for the text controls.